# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource in python to angular socket io

Tags: angular, python-socketio

socketio can't get the data from python to angular front end it shows the error as
"`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://my ip:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NQtJeHE. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)`"

```
while True:
    sio.emit('livedata', {data'})
```

Didn't get this into **angular from python socketio emits** shows the above error

Answer (score 1):

`python-socketio` enforces a [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) by default. This means that if your socketio server is running on `http://myip:5000`, then it will only accept requests from that origin. So in your case, it's blocking requests from your angular frontend because the request is coming from `http://myip:3000`

Per the [python-socketio documentation](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/server.html#cross-origin-controls):

> If necessary, the cors_allowed_origins option can be used to allow other origins. This argument can be set to a string to set a single allowed origin, or to a list to allow multiple origins. A special value of '*' can be used to instruct the server to allow all origins, but this should be done with care, as this could make the server vulnerable to Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) attacks.

**How to fix:**

Initialize your `python-socketio` server with a list of origins you want to allow requests from. In this case, that's your angular application and your python application. Use something like the following (assuming your python server is running locally on port 5000 and angular on 3000):

`sio = socketio.Server(cors_allowed_origins=['http://myip:5000',  'http://myip:3000'])`

And it should now work.

***Note***: you can also do the following, but this will accept requests from **ALL** origins, so be careful as it can open you up to CSRF attacks:

`sio = socketio.Server(cors_allowed_origins='*')`

***Additional note***: if you're using `flask-socketio` (the Flask extension wrapper of `python-socketio`), just pass the same `cors_allowed_origins` argument into the `SocketIO` object when you initialize (or the `init_app` method). You'll also need to enable CORS on your Flask application - I'd recommend using and reading the documentation on [Flask-CORS](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) extension - it makes it very simple.

Comment: How this emit work to a specific port using socket io server it works with client?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking. SocketIO will emit to the clients that are connected (whatever their port is)...it's up to you to specify who is allowed to connect when you initialize the server...which I described to you above. The reason it's not working now is because the default SocketIO server configuration doesn't allow `http://myip:3000` to connect, as it's outside the origin your Python server is running on (most likely `http://myip:5000`).

Comment: By the server can't handle more than one connection at a time why? I mention socket.listen(100) but  a connection is happening at a time only for one endpoint

Answer (score 0):

Using async mode threading for multiprocessing and cros for the security can use

> cors_allowed_origins=['*']
> for all

```
import threading
socketio = SocketIO(app,cors_allowed_origins=['http://pythonserver-ip:port','http://angular-ip:4200'],async_mode='threading')
```

for sleep in while loop use this code instead of time.sleep(2)

```
socketio.sleep(2)
```